# Cause: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-view, kotlin-android

I have a problem on android studio. It keeps giving this error and i don't know why. I have a blank view and activity with just the default code and it still shows this on every activity or project i create

I've tried using my phone instead of a virtual device, it still didn't work. I'm not really sure what to do. Its just a blank activity and view on android studio. I've tried putting code. nothing works. please help!
[My Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74X13.png)

[After I Run It On Android Virtual Machine Pixel 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Ryc.png)

Comment: Can you share the error logs or the screenshots depicting what issue you are facing?